# Проблема с масштабом игрового окна

Tags: unity3d

Делаю 2D-игру в Unity. Столкнулся с такой проблемой - при нажатии на кнопку "Start" (включаю игру), масштаб игрового окна резко увеличивается с мною поставленного 0,3x до 1,3x. Для вас сделал специальный Canvas, чтобы показать проблему. Кто знает, почему так?[image: Скриншот, слева - до старта, справа - после старта]